# Funcion no elimina registro en BBDD mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, funciones

He creado una función en mysql cuya misión es eliminar un registro de la tabla 'departamento'. Tiene la restricción de no se puede eliminar el departamento si en la tabla 'empleado' alguno de ellos lo tiene asignado.
La función hace todo lo que debe, no lo elimina si existe y tiene empleados, ni si el nombre está mal escrito o no existe.
Pero no me elimina el departamento aunque no tenga empleados asociados

Esta es la tabla 'departamento'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta la tabla 'empleado'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este el código de la función:

```
 DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE eliminar_departamento(IN nom_departamento VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE nom_Dept VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE num_Dpt INT;
DECLARE tiene_empl INT;

SET nom_Dept:=(SELECT departamento.nombre FROM departamento WHERE departamento.nombre=nom_departamento); /*Buscamos si existe el deparamento*/
SET num_Dpt:=(SELECT departamento.num_dpt FROM departamento WHERE departamento.nombre=nom_departamento); /*Buscamos el número del departamento*/
SET tiene_empl:=(SELECT Num_dpt FROM empleado WHERE Num_dpt=num_dpt LIMIT 1); /*Buscamos si en empleados alguno tiene asignado ese departamento*/

/*Si el departamento no existe o está mal escrito*/
IF(nom_Dept IS NULL) 
THEN SELECT 'El departamento no existe o está mal escrito.' AS 'TIPO DE ERROR'; 
END IF;

/*Si el departamento tiene empleados*/
IF(tiene_empl IS NOT NULL)
THEN SELECT 'El departamento tiene empleados y no se puede borrar.' AS 'TIPO DE ERROR';
END IF;

/*Si todo lo anterior no sucede, borramos departamento*/
IF (nom_Dept IS NOT NULL AND tiene_empl IS NULL) THEN DELETE FROM departamento WHERE departamento.nombre=nom_departamento;
SELECT 'Departamento eliminado' AS 'Resultado del procedimiento';
END IF;

END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

¿Alguna ayuda o sugerencia? Si intento borrar el registro 5 de 'departamento', el que se llama 'Playa y piscina', me dice que no lo puede eliminar porque tiene empleados asignados y no tiene ninguno

Comment: Mejor que un `describe`, convendría que nos muestres la estructura de la tabla, puedes obtenerla mediante la consulta `SHOW CREATE TABLE departamento;` y, en vez de una captura de pantalla, copia y pega el texto, es más simple para ti y mejor para que podamos analizar el problema. Si no te deja eliminar es quizá porque en la tabla hayas declarado una regla de integridad referencial, lo sabremos cuando veamos el `CREATE TABLE`. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que por defecto en MySQL no es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas. Entonces en tu sentencia donde estás validando si tiene empleados estás haciendo referencia a la misma columna:

```
SET tiene_empl:=(SELECT Num_dpt FROM empleado WHERE Num_dpt=num_dpt LIMIT 1);
```

Num_dpt y num_dpt estan haciendo referencia a la columna num_dpt en la tabla empleado, por eso el tiene_empl siempre te va a devolver un registro.

Para solucionarlo, podes renombrar la variable "Num_dpt" de tu stored procedure:

```
DECLARE id_Dpt INT;

SET id_Dpt:=(SELECT departamento.num_dpt FROM departamento WHERE departamento.nombre=nom_departamento); 

SET tiene_empl:=(SELECT num_dpt FROM empleado WHERE num_dpt=id_Dpt LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, ese era justamente el error.
Acabo de dejar de un lado Java y se me pasó por alto que SQL no es case sensitive.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda...no se como cerrar la pregunta, o si queda asi
Gracias de nuevo @manuxo